# Google Search with sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-2010, google-search, sharepointfoundation2010

Can I use google search to crowl only in both my sharepoint portal and my website
when I searched I found Google Search Appliance http://www.google.com/enterprise/search/gsa.html but its not free

I used Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2010

Can I use alternative way for that

All ideas are welcome

Best Regards,

Mohammed Thabet Zaky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SharePoint search to search both SharePoint and your website.
Just add content sources from search administration.

Comment: thanks Nico, I used Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Is it support Search ?

Comment: No. But you can use Search Server Express (http://www.microsoft.com/enterprisesearch/searchserverexpress/en/us/default.aspx). It's free and works very well.